# How to search for In-App transaction in Huawei AppGallery

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-iap

I have published my app in Huawei AppGallery.
Users make purchases (In-App), I can only see the number of purchases the next day.

But I can’t verify the user’s purchase in any way, but only believe them.
In Google Play, I can enter the email or GPA number of the purchase and check when it was made and if the transaction was successful.

In Huawei AppGallery, I did not find this anywhere. Can you please tell me where can I find this option?
After all, it is the most important option for developers, I do not believe that it does not exist. I also need to know about the purchase this day, not the next day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the developer console, you could download the report as shown below
[image]

To track real-time transaction results, you could add ["viewing the purchase history"](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/dev-guide-0000001050130254#section1877319452446) in your app. Once this history is successfully obtained, you could either pass it to your server or save it in the app.

Alternatively, you could confirm the purchase by verifying the purchase token [(from InAppPurchaseData)](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References/json-inapppurchasedata-0000001050986125) to confirm the purchase as well.

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment, I misread your answer. Thank you very much! It's almost all that i need. But it's not possible to search for purchase by user e-mail? Only by Transaction ID?

Comment: There is no such capability in AGC to search IAP records by email.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you can go to Developer Center > My Report > Payment Report.
You can search for all subscriptions under your app by keywords such as the app ID, time, and order status.
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/console#/myReport/payment

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It's almost all that i need. But it's not possible to search for purchase by user e-mail? Only by Transaction ID?

Comment: Yes，it is not supported.